# Deny all pages without login on Asp.net Web Forms with Identity Framework and Owin

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-identity, owin

How do I set up a web forms application  with identity and owin to deny all pages except the login?

This configuration in web.config not work for me:

```
 <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
    <authentication mode="None"/>
```

**Error message:** The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long.

**OWIN startup class:**

```
 public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

            // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
            // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
            // Configure the sign in cookie
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, Usuario>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => manager.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(user))
                }
            });
```

Project structure
[image]

**Edit:**

On web.config inside account folder there is this  configuration.

```
<configuration>

  <location path="Manage.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

</configuration>
```

This works for Manage.aspx page.

I do not want to do this for every page. I want to put in the global web.config of the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in asp.net identity with friendlyurls.

https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/discussions/571688

Comment: 2016...Is still a bug... your link seems broken.

Answer (score 3):

I experimented a lot with `Web.config` and always had errors as already described here. Then I gave it up and just added a filter to `Global.asax`

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string cTheFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path;
  if (!cTheFile.EndsWith("Login"))
  {
    if (HttpContext.Current.User == null || 
      HttpContext.Current.User.Identity == null || 
      !HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
      Response.Redirect("~/Account/Login", true);
      Response.End();
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

This worked well for me, although I m not sure, if it is an optimal solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can just configure it in your web.config like this:

```
<system.web>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
        <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
</system.web>
<location path="Login.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

**EDIT**: Added configuration for extra long request string

If your request becomes too long, you can add this in your web.config to overcome the problem:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
     <requestFiltering>
         <requestLimits maxQueryString="nnn"/>
     </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

I hope this fixes it now.

Comment: This configuration not work. Erro message: The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long.

Comment: I think this should not be necessary. The url should not be long.

Answer (score -1):

if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
stay on page
}
else
{
transfer to another
}

Comment: I think it is not necessary to do this hard code validation.